# Converting list of both "word strings" and "number strings" to a list where the "number strings" are converted to just numbers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I realize my wording for the title isn't the best, but I hope an example will clear this up.

How would I convert a list like

```
example_list = ["asdf" , "4", "asdfasdf" , "8" , "9" ,"asdf"]
```

to a list like

```
converted_list = ["asdf" , 4, "asdfasdf", 8 , 9 , "asdf"]
```

So basically how do I make a list where strings that can be converted to integers are converted to integers while strings that cannot be converted remain as strings?

As a side note, how would I afterwards test in a for loop if each item in the `converted_list` is an integer or not?

The context for this issue is that I am trying to convert headers in pandas to integers if possible, since all the integers are strings as of now. And then if the column had a stringed number as a header, I would take the mean of the column. Right now, I have made all the headers into a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a ternary to determine whether or not each element of the list is a number.

```
>>> [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in example_list]
['asdf', 4, 'asdfasdf', 8, 9, 'asdf']
```

Comment: I used a clumsy way of forming the dictionary.  But you can use your insight in this dictionary comprehension for use in a `rename` call.  `df.rename(columns={k: int(k) for k in df.columns if k.isdigit()})`.  I'll likely start using this (-:

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer.
Is there a reason why 
data_frame_names = list(df.columns.values)
#print (data_frame_names)
digitize = [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in data_frame_names]
#print(digitize)
for x in digitize:
    if isinstance(x,int):
        print (df[df.columns[x]].mean())
    else:
        pass

keeps giving this error TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Did you first rename your columns? See comment from @piRSquared above. Note that you need to reassign the result, e.g. `df = df.rename(...)`.

Comment: When I imported all the csv files I renamed duplicates, but do I need to rename them again? Also what do you mean by reassign the result? Do I need to do something after your method to be able to use the new list in a for loop? Sorry for the needed clarification, I am new to python
Edit: I renamed the columns again and I am still getting this error

Comment: `df.columns = [int(n) if n.isdigit() else n for n in df]`, then `print(df[x].mean())`

Comment: so that works, but for some reason it only gives me the mean of one column(i dont know which) but I need the means of multiple different columns (unique means, not total mean)

when i use the for loop now i get 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'/////////////////// is there anything wrong with my forloop for finding the columns with digits as headers for x in data_frame_names:
    if isinstance(x,int):
        print (df[df.columns[x]].mean())
    else:
        pass

Comment: `df[[col for col in df if isinstance(col, int)]].mean()`

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to be working fine now

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
example_list = ["asdf" , "4", "asdfasdf" , "8" , "9" ,"asdf"]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(4, 6), columns=example_list)

df

   asdf   4  asdfasdf   8   9  asdf
0     0   1         2   3   4     5
1     6   7         8   9  10    11
2    12  13        14  15  16    17
3    18  19        20  21  22    23
```

---

**Convert Headers**

```
df.rename(columns={k: int(k) for k in df.columns[df.columns.str.isdigit()]})

   asdf   4  asdfasdf   8   9  asdf
0     0   1         2   3   4     5
1     6   7         8   9  10    11
2    12  13        14  15  16    17
3    18  19        20  21  22    23
```

**Note**
@Alexander's use of the string method `isdigit` within a list comprehension is extremely useful.  We can improve this answer by combining with his.

```
df.rename(columns={k: int(k) for k in df.columns if k.isdigit()})
```

---

**Look at Types**

```
df.rename(
    columns={k: int(k) for k in df.columns[df.columns.str.isdigit()]}
).columns.map(type)

Index([<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>,
       <class 'int'>, <class 'str'>],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: OP says - `I am trying to convert headers in pandas` - so mybe list is column names :)

Comment: Thx @jezrael.  I've updated my answer a bit.